# Add short toc entry to toc entry and vice versa

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir

Taking heavy inspiration from the answer to:

[Hide toc from toc, and shorttoc from shorttoc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/446295/hide-toc-from-toc-and-shorttoc-from-shorttoc)

I have made the following code:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\newcommand{\shorttoc}{%
\renewcommand*{\contentsname}{Short Contents}
\begingroup%
\def\inshorttoc{}%
\tableofcontents*%
\addtocontents{toc}{\string\ifdefined\string\inshorttoc\string\else}%
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\contentsname}%
\addtocontents{toc}{\string\fi}%
\endgroup%
}

\newcommand{\toc}{%
\renewcommand*{\contentsname}{Contents}
\begingroup%
\def\intoc{}
\tableofcontents*
\addtocontents{toc}{\string\ifdefined\string\intoc\string\else}%
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\contentsname}%
\addtocontents{toc}{\string\fi}%
\endgroup%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}
\shorttoc

\cleardoublepage

\toc

\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

It should place the short contents entry into the long toc and vice versa. But after updating my TeX live distribution the code throws the errors:

```
Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup. \@writefile{toc}{\fi}
Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup. \@writefile{toc}{\fi}
```

But the code compiles without errors on older distributions.

Comment: Are you sure this has ever worked?

Comment: Yes it works if I compile it on Overleaf

Comment: Why not doing the test outside of the toc? Something like `\newif\ifintoc \ifintoc \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{foo}\fi` instead of writing tricky `\if...` stuff into the `.aux` and then to the `.toc` file?

Comment: I would be happy with another solution, but I cannot get your suggestion to work. Will "foo" not be added to both shorttoc and toc as along as intoc is true at some point in the document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking into the newer releases of LaTeX I found out that the @\writefile command has been changed slightly (see pages 269--271 in the 2018-12-01 version of the LaTeX2e source documentation, a link is https://www.latex-project.org/help/documentation/source2e.pdf) to solve some problems with spurious spaces. Using the old definition of the @writefile command solved the problem, it is:

```
\long\def\@writefile#1#2{%
  \@ifundefined{tf@#1}\relax
    {\@temptokena{#2}%
     \immediate\write\csname tf@#1\endcsname{\the\@temptokena}%
    }%
}
```

A proper solution would avoid this redefinition of @writefile.